# InvalidCastException on Casting dynamic object in C# using CsharpScript

Tags: c#

I am creating dynamically object which is anonymous type in this code:

```
 public class SomeClass{
        public static object Run()
            {
                var builder = new StringBuilder("new { FilmSourceId = 2, Source = \"Something\" }");
        
                return CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(builder.ToString()).Result;
        }
    }
```

I have this kind of Select function which throws exception when casting:

```
 class Program
        {
            static TResult Select<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> selector)
            {
                return (TResult)SomeClass.Run();//this throws Exception
            }
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var k = Select((Person p) => new { FilmSourceId = 2, Source = p.Name});
            }
    }
```

Exception text:

> Unable to cast object of type `` <>f__AnonymousType0#1`2[System.Int32,System.String] `` to type `` <>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.String] ``.

This code is only for demonstration from real code, but I have this problem in real code too. Any ideas why it is happening and how to fix it?

Update: if I will have function which is not creating dynamically object then it works:

```
 public static object Run(Type t)
    {
       return new {FilmSourceId = 2, Source = "Something" };
}
```

Comment: It seems that `EvaluateAsync` is unable to reuse the anonymous type generated when your main project's code is compiled. I'd guess that `EvaluateAsync` might be building its own assembly, though I could be wrong. You might have to look at using a known type, or something like a `ValueTuple` or `ExpandoObject` instead.

Comment: You simply can't do this: anonymous types are unable to cross assembly boundaries (which the language enforces by making sure that they can't cross method boundaries, and can't be fields). The reason is that each assembly will contain its own compiler-generated definition for an anonymous type with that "shape". You need to return a type which both the calling assembly and the script assembly know about

Comment: Your "Update" won't work if the "Run" method and "Main" method are in different assemblies, which is the issue with your script